# Generate PDF file without using third party DLL

Tags: c#

Can you please help me in generating PDF file using c# and without using 3rd party dll?
Expect all possible solutions/ideas/suggestions.

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: You could write a book on this question. It's far too broad a question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a rdlc file and export it to PDF using the built-in function of ReportViewer.
Using ReportViewer you can also create a report and export it to PDF at runtime (without preview).

Answer (score 1):

Is the pdf fromat a strict requirement? If not, it is a bit easier to create html or rtf documents, if you can't use 3 part libraries.

If it is a requirement, you can create a pdfdocument ([example here](http://www.gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF)) and create a text-template ([like this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9010/A-Text-Template-Class-for-C)) to replace the data you want.